# db_query to drupal variable

Tags: database, configuration

I have a the following query:

```
function background_audio_file_query($path) {
  $result = db_query("SELECT uri
    FROM `file_managed`
    WHERE `filemime` = 'audio/mpeg'
    LIMIT 1 , 30",
    array(':uri'=>$path))->fetch();

return $result;
}
```

How can I pass this to a Drupal variable?  I am assuming `variable_set()` but I am having trouble with the syntax.  Could anyone lend a hand?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a variable with the URI returned from the query, you just execute code similar to the following one:

```
variable_set('variable name', $result->uri);
```

Replace "variable name" with the name you want to give to the Drupal variable, which is the same one you pass to `variable_get()`.

Comment: In that way, the value name is always 'variable name', not the actual variable name ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your result, [variable_set syntax](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7) is simply name, value:

```
variable_set('background_audio', 'meep.au');
```

Does that answer your question?

Comment: In that way, the value is always "meep.au" not the result from the query.